# How do you configure Spinnaker to use an ElastiCache redis cluster?

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

Following the [instructions here](https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/halyard/custom/), I am attempting to configure Spinnaker to use an ElastiCache redis cluster, with cluster mode enabled.

```
Spinnaker: 1.40.2
Halyard: 0.35
Cloud driver provider: k8s (1.7.4)
Cloud: AWS
```

I have an ElastiCache Redis cluster configured in cluster mode, it has its configuration endpoint:

```
redis-spinnaker.1234.clustercfg.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379
```

It has one node:

I have created the following file: `halyard/default/service-settings/redis.yml`

```
overrideBaseUrl: redis://redis-spinnaker.1234.clustercfg.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379
```

I also tried

```
overrideBaseUrl: redis://redis-spinnaker-0001-001.1234.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379
```

Note that both of these addresses are accessible from the cluster.

When I run `halyard deploy apply`, `spin-gate` times out

```
/ Deploy spin-gate
  Timed out

And the whole deploy times out.
Problems in Global:
! ERROR Unexpected exception:
  DaemonTaskInterrupted(interruptedTime=1507614194943, message=Task interrupted at
  Tue Oct 10 05:43:14 UTC 2017 with message: Interrupted during reap by exception:
  null)

- Failed to deploy Spinnaker. Task killed because it was taking too
  long.
```

At this point, I'm not sure what to do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot make spinnaker work with clustered / replicated elasticache redis, so what I do is use only a single ElastiCache redis node and then set  `service.redis.host` in `spinnaker-local.yml` to the appropriate redis endpoint and set `redis.configuration.secure` in `gate-local.yml` to true

Comment: It was a combination of things, but the key was that I was using the `clustered` mode.  So this felt like the key piece of information that solved my issue.  I also set `overrideBaseUrl` in `service-settings/redis.yml` and `redis.configuration.secure: true` in `profiles/gate-local.yml`

Answer (score 2):

I'm making some progress with elasticache redis like so:

```
$ cat .hal/default/service-settings/redis.yml 
overrideBaseUrl: redis://xxx.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379

$ cat .hal/default/profiles/gate-local.yml 
redis:
  configuration:
    secure: true
```

the gate-local.yml change came from https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/1309#issuecomment-260971228

not 100% sure it works but at least all the spinnaker services start up and it is superficially working even after I kill off the redis replica set that halyard starts up

Comment: I wonder about adding `targetSize: 0` to prevent creation of `redis` and `redisBootstrap`, or even the right way to do that.  https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/halyard/custom/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a set of instructions for anyone else that wants to use an external redis (based on my [GH issue](https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/2034#issuecomment-337248475)):

```
# ~/.hal/default/service-settings/redis.yml
enabled: false
overrideBaseUrl: redis://:password@c1.us-central1-2.gce.cloud.redislabs.com:6379

# ~/.hal/default/service-settings/redis-bootstrap.yml
enabled: false
overrideBaseUrl: redis://:password@c1.us-central1-2.gce.cloud.redislabs.com:6379
```

Specific to elasticache as @DavidBlack said, you also need

```
# ~/.hal/default/profiles/gate-local.yml 
redis:
  configuration:
    secure: true
```

Follow this by deleting replica sets, services etc, or perhaps more simply (depending on your situation):
`hal deploy clean && hal deploy apply`

If you `hal deploy clean`, don't forget to re-apply any additional configs (like external IP to kubernetes services if you have set them up).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using the Spinnaker operator, I got elasticsearch redis working with the following settings:

- Redis Version: 5.0.6
- Cluster Mode enabled: No
- Encryption in-transit: Yes
- Encryption at-rest: Yes
- Redis AUTH: Yes

k8s secret: rediss://:AUTH_TOKEN@master.spinnaker-test.XXX.YYY.cache.amazonaws.com:6379

```
profiles:
  gate:
    redis:
      configuration:
        secure: true

service-settings:  
  redis:
    overrideBaseUrl: encrypted:k8s!n:spinnaker-secrets!k:redis-url-dev
    skipLifeCycleManagement: true
```

Once this is deployed you need to manually delete the Redis deployment the operator created previously.